# apt-add-repository problem via proxy since xubuntu 16.10 (work in xubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, xubuntu, proxy, 16.10

I have a virtual machine with xubuntu 16.04. Since the upgrade to 16.10, I can't add ppa (via apt-add-repository command)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
[sudo] password for me: 
 Quick howto to turn your machine into an X2Go server:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
sudo apt-get install x2gomatebindings  # if you use MATE/mubuntu
sudo apt-get install x2golxdebindings  # if you use LXDE/lubuntu

Quick howto to install the x2goclient:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x2goclient

Enjoy!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~x2go/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpts0fs2o5/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host
```

I try with

```
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:x2go/stable
```

same problem

my configuration proxy
in /etc/profile.d/my_conf.sh

```
export http_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
export https_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
export ftp_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,..."
export HTTP_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
export FTP_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,..."
```

in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://my.proxy:80/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://my.proxy:80/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://my.proxy:80/";
```

I have also tried to add this...
in /etc/environment

```
http_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
https_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
ftp_proxy="http://my.proxy:80"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,..."
HTTP_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
FTP_PROXY="http://my.proxy:80"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,..."
```

If I add gpg key manually with

```
gpg --import newkey.txt
```

It works...

I think the problem came from gpg update due to the upgrade of xubuntu 16.10

Can anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem on Ubuntu 17.04. 
I had to manually add repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list